# Behind code for button being not updated with new code in Facebook app

Tags: c#, facebook-c#-sdk

I have what appears to me to be a really bizarre issue. I'm experimenting with the asp.net webforms project( from the C# Facebook SDK) and everything works fine. That is until I try and change the behind code; for example in the 'Post To Wall' button. No matter what I change the code to inside the button click event, it never runs when I upload it to the server, it always appears to run the old code (which isn't even there any more in the file!) - is there some kind of caching going on with Facebook? There is no problem with adding new buttons but the behind code for them cant be changed either when run once. It basically means I cant work with it as any new behind code I add isn't picked up when I run the app inside Facebook. Even more bizarrely I can change the name of the button and that is displayed fine, but any new behind code is ignored. Am I missing something simple here..............

Cheers,

Derek

Comment: Maybe your server is keeping the previous version in cache and failed to update the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you seeing the code behind in the servered HTML? Are you sure you compiled the application before you uploaded it?  Maybe a dll in the bin file is not being correctly updated.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the aspx stuff will simply refresh with a save, but the compiled Server code will need a refresh if you haven't done so already.

You can restart your web server (if IIS restart the App pool), that'll start using your new application dll.

If that doesn't work, try using fiddler if there's an http call going out Facebook to see if the call is correct.